# FFmpeg calculating incorrect duration for image to MP4 video build

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, concatenation

I am trying tobuild a 15 second MP4 file (beach.mp4) - from 3 static images that show for 3, 5 and 7 seconds in sequence.
However, the total MP4 duration built by FFmpeg is 19 seconds. So 4 seconds are being added on somewhere, this also applies when using `duration`.
The image sizes are 1920px x 1080px, which should conform with the yuv420p command

SEQUENCE.TXT

`file beach1.jpg outpoint 3 file beach2.jpg outpoint 8 file beach3.jpg outpoint 15`

FFMPEG COMMAND

`ffmpeg -f concat -i sequence.txt -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest beach.mp4`

You can download or view the files at https://lifeisabeach.netlify.app/ (For some strange reason the MP4 length when built locally is 19 seconds, when it should be 15!)

Where are the extra seconds coming from? How can I instruct FFmpeg to calculate the exact duration?

Comment: Link is broken.